# Repairing solutions in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Recently I encounter something interesting that I hope to hear from your opinions:

Suppose we are given a ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=y$, with no initial condition.

Naively, we divide both sides by $y$ and use the separation of variables. (This is a very typical mistake that many high school students will commit, I myself did commit such an error back then :P)

We will get a general solution: $y=A\exp(x)$. We can plot the trajectories out by varying the value of $A$.

If the initial condition is to be $y(0)=0$, then again, naively we substitute into the $y=A\exp(x)$, hence yielding $A=0$, which means $y$ is identically equals to $0$.

I know the naive steps involved are incorrect, especially the one that involves division by $y$ throughout. But at the end of the day, the general solution seems to have the ability of "repairing" this mistake by allowing $A=0$.

However, when the ODE changes to the following: $\frac{dy}{dx}=y(y-1)$. Then I encounter difficulty in "repairing" the solution. According to my working, the general solution is $y=\frac{1}{1-A\exp(x)}$. I can "repair" the mistake made for initial condition $y(0)=1$ by setting $A=0$, but I cannot "repair" the result for the initial condition $y(0)=0$.

I have a hunch that these might be related to the attracting/repelling orbits/trajectories. From the plotting of the trajectories for these two questions, I notice that those trajectories that I can "repair" the solution are repelling trajectories. Perhaps I am thinking too much.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @bof thank you for your reply. I agree that by doing some algebraic manipulations, you can account for the "repairing" to obtain the other solution. However, by writing $\frac{1}{B}$, you are assuming $B$ to be non-zero. In addition, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form, unless we set it to be 1.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This question is about "repairing" the solution of a ODE using two examples. The "repairing" is to account for trivial solutions that often one might miss out in using separation of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing one should do is to notice that $y=0$ and $y=1$ are constant solutions, and that all other solutions are given by $\int\frac{dy}{y(y-1)}=\int dx$, which leads to $y=1/(1-A e^x)$ where $A \neq 0$ (this condition should follow from your integration if you are careful; when solving for $y$, there's some step where you exponentiate an arbitrary integration constant $C$ to get an arbitrary *positive* constant $B$, and then when you remove absolute value signs you get $A=\pm B$ which can be anything except zero).

In general you can't expect to be able to write the whole solution with one single formula. In this case you can patch it partially by allowing $A$ to be zero (since you notice that this recovers one the constant solutions that you noticed separately at the beginning):
$$
y=0
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
y=\frac{1}{1-Ae^x}
\quad
(A\in \mathbf{R})
.
$$
But you might as well first replace the arbitrary nonzero constant $A$ by the equally arbitrary and nonzero constant $a=1/A$, rewrite $1/(1-(1/a)e^x)=a/(a-e^x)$, and then patch by allowing $a$ to be zero:
$$
y=1
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
y=\frac{a}{a-e^x}
\quad
(a\in \mathbf{R})
.
$$
Both these ways of writing are equally valid ways of describing the set of solutions.
So whether you are able to patch or not has nothing to do with repelling or attracting solutions.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. I can understand from your working, you consider cases, which is the correct method. However, I am wondering why we cannot write the general solution in a single formula. I know existence and uniqueness theorem guarantees the solution. This problem is not an IVP. It is later that we change to an IVP to see how robust our general solution can be. For your second solution, it seems that your $a$ can be $0$, which will be a little awkward since you define $a=\frac{1}{A}$. Can you rectify that portion to make it convincing? Thank you.

Comment: The notion of attracting/repelling stuff came when I was plotting the trajectories for the differential equations. I do not know whether there is any link to these patchings that you have suggested, or it is just solely algebraic manipulations.:) You may be right; I am thinking too much.

Comment: At first, $a=1/A$ with $A \neq 0$, so that $a \neq 0$. Then the solution is $y=0$ or $y=1$ or $y=a/(a-e^x)$ with $a \neq 0$. But then, *afterwards*, one notices that setting $a=0$ gives $y=0$, so that one case can be eliminated, and the solution written more simply as $y=1$ or $y=a/(a-e^x)$ with $a \in \mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

As this question was referenced from [Determining $y' = 1 - y^2$ generally excludes $y = \pm 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2027147/115115) and the reduction to the initial condition was not mentioned in the other answer, here a late remark:

---

One can always try to reduce the constant to the initial condition. Or to avoid arbitrary constants, when integrating the partial fractions, use definite integrals, not indefinite integrals with arbitrary constants. Its a little more work, but the "repaired" formula appears automatically.
$$
x=\int_{y_0}^y\frac{du}{u(u-1)}=\ln\frac{y-1}{y_0-1}-\ln\frac{y}{y_0}
$$
transforms into
$$
(y-1)y_0=(y_0-1)ye^x\iff y(y_0-(y_0-1)e^x)=y_0
\\~\\
\iff y(x)=\frac{y_0}{y_0+(1-y_0)e^x}
$$
which around $x=0$ is valid for all $y_0$ and also includes the constant solutions for $y_0=0$ and $y_0=1$.